# How can I use an SSL certificate generated with Java keytool with Nginx?

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, https, private-key

I used the Java keytool to generate a "keystore":

```
keytool -genkey -alias example.com -keyalg RSA -keystore example.com.keystore
```

Then I generated a CSR (Certificate Signing Request):

```
keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -alias example.com -file example.com.csr
-keystore example.com.keystore
```

Then I issued an certificate and saved it in a textfile `example.com.crt`

Now I want to use this certificate with Nginx.

I have placed my certificate on `/etc/ssl/certs/example.com.cert`
and I placed my "keystore" (I think it contains my private key?) on `/etc/ssl/private/example.com.keystore`

Then I configured my Nginx following [Nginx, SSL and vhosts](http://articles.slicehost.com/2007/12/19/ubuntu-gutsy-nginx-ssl-and-vhosts). But when I reload the Nginx configuration file I get this error message:

```
sudo service nginx reload
Reloading nginx configuration: [emerg]: SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file("/etc/ssl/certs/myssl.crt") failed (SSL: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line error:140DC009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:PEM lib)
configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

When I followed the same guide and generated an SSL-certificate using `openssl` it worked fine. But using Java keytool I get this error.

How can I use a SSL-certificate and keys from Java keytool with Nginx?

Comment: Check [here](https://gist.github.com/pymeat/6606011). They have given easy steps to follow.

Comment: The link ink is broken

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a keystore with just about anything not written in Java, as far as I know. It's also not possible to extract the key with `keytool`.

I'd recommend using something like http://www.openssl.org/docs/HOWTO/keys.txt or the `easy-rsa`-tools included with OpenVPN to generate a new key/certificate-combo, which will by default be generated in a format readable by nginx.

If it is important to extract the key from the keystore, there's a guide at http://conshell.net/wiki/index.php/Keytool_to_OpenSSL_Conversion_tips on how to extract it.

Comment: I think this is wrong or outdated..... You can extract your keys with Keystore. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3779/how-can-i-export-my-private-key-from-a-java-keytool-keystore